# Serializable schedules but not view serializable

Tags: databases

I know that to check if a given schedule is serializable we can test for either view serializability or conflict serializability. But do serializable schedules exist which are not view serializable?

Answer (score 0):

No.
There doesn't exist any serializable schedule which is not view serializable.